# How Do I Transform This CSV / Tabular Data Into A Different Shape?

Tags: excel, csv

I have a sparse n-column spreadsheet where the first two columns describe a person and the rest of the (n-2) columns track RSVP and attendance data for various events (each of which take up one column).  It looks like this:

```
    PersonID, Name, Event29108294, Event01838401, Event10128384
    12345, John Smith, Registered - NoShow, Registered and Attended, RSVPed Maybe and did not attend
    982348, Mary Levitsky, Registered - NoShow, RSVPed No, 
    1873218, Alexa Maris, , Registered and Attended, 
    8294, Katlyn Johnson, , , Registered and Attended
```

I need to load it into a database that stores attendance information as "1 row per populated junction of a person & an event."  Therefore, I need to transform the data to look like this:

```
    EventID, PersonID, PersonName, Status
    Event29108294, 12345, John Smith, Registered - NoShow
    Event29108294, 982348, Mary Levitsky, Registered - NoShow
    Event01838401, 12345, John Smith, Registered and Attended
    Event01838401, 982348, Mary Levitsky, RSVPed No
    Event01838401, 1873218, Alexa Maris, Registered and Attended
    Event10128384, 12345, John Smith, RSVPed Maybe and did not attend
    Event10128384, 8294, Katlyn Johnson, Registered and Attended
```

*(I know it's not normal form to include the names ... they won't be in the final data load ... but they'd be nice for human proofreading before doing the data load.)*

How can I do this with Excel, or with any other tool easily accessible to a Windows PC user?  *(I have Excel, Microsoft LogParser, Microsoft Access, and PortablePython installed already.)*

Thank you!

-K

Comment: You need to create a file to go into a database, not get the information into excel (pivot table)?

Comment: Correct - the top sample is the way the data was stored when a single tab of a spreadsheet WAS acting as both a contact management database and an event attendance management database.  The bottom sample is the way the data needs to look to go in its new home in the EventAttendanceByContacts table of a proper relational database with 3 tables:  Contacts, Events, & EventAttendanceByContacts.

Comment: Is your data for events in different cells or one cell with commas?

Comment: It's in different cells.  As I mentioned, there could be up to "n-2" columns worth of event data.   The department that's been tracking by spreadsheet has been simply adding columns over time as they run more events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your events are in different columns, something like this would work -

```vb
Sub test()
Dim wsOrig As Worksheet
Set wsOrig = ActiveSheet

Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Set wsDest = Sheets("Sheet2")

Dim lcol As Integer
lcol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Dim lrow As Integer
lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

Dim x As Integer
x = 2

wsDest.Cells(1, 1) = "EventID"
wsDest.Cells(1, 2) = wsOrig.Cells(1, 1)
wsDest.Cells(1, 3) = wsOrig.Cells(1, 2)
wsDest.Cells(1, 4) = "Status"


For i = 2 To lrow
    For j = 3 To lcol
        If Cells(i, j) <> "" Then
            wsDest.Cells(x, 1) = wsOrig.Cells(1, j)
            wsDest.Cells(x, 2) = wsOrig.Cells(i, 1)
            wsDest.Cells(x, 3) = wsOrig.Cells(i, 2)
            wsDest.Cells(x, 4) = wsOrig.Cells(i, j)
            x = x + 1
        End If
    Next
 Next


End Sub
```

If you're in a .csv you may need to avoid using two sheets. Also, there might be a more elegant way to do this with an array.